# Cannot capture a click event on images created on the fly

Tags: jquery, events, click, refresh

There is a row of images in a Joomla module, I click on one and I have a jQuery click event opening a 2nd module that has a row of images created on the fly. There is no page refresh. The newly created row is formatted like this:

```
<img class="newmanugroup" data-manu="companyA" src="images/logos/companyA.png">
<img class="newmanugroup" data-manu="companyB" src="images/logos/companyB.png">
<img class="newmanugroup" data-manu="companyC" src="images/logos/companyC.png">
```

This little image array shows in Chrome's Inspect Element, couched in a nice little Joomla `<div id="prodgroup">`. I can get a jQuery click result from #prodgroup which does me no good for this purpose. But the image array shown above that I want to click on shows on screen but does not show in the page source. Whaaa??? Shouldn't that array be in the DOM if it is on screen, and shouldn't I be able to get a click event? Is all this because I haven't done a page refresh? I don't even know how to begin to approach this.

Comment: You must rebind every time a new item is added to your page, otherwise jQuery don't know it's there and can'T trigger actions on it.

Comment: Please post your jQuery code.

Comment: use `.on()` handler with event delegation to `#prodgroup`.

Answer (score 3):

You need the `event delegation` with `.on()` handler:

```
$(document).on('click', '.newmanugroup', function(){
   alert('Do Something.');
});
```

Comment: This way ended up working for me: jQuery(document).bind('click', '#prodgroup', function(){jQuery('.newmanugroup').click(function() { alert('finally it saw the click on the image' }; console.log(this););  And the console log shows <img class="newmanugroup" data-manu="companyA" src="images/logos/companyA.png">

Comment: When I tried to use 'on' instead of 'bind', in the console log I get "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'"